# Select2 reinitialize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have a selectbox, which is dependent on another selectbox. I'm using AJAX to change options on the second (dependent) selectbox. Also, I'm using select2 plugin on both of the selectboxes, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mySelect2').select2({
        // options
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that after refreshing the second selectbox, select2 just disappears from this selectbox and shows to me just like a normal selectbox. Somewhere here, I have seen that I can use destroy and "reinit" the select. But in mySelect1.onChange event when I use:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2("destroy");
$('#mySelect2').select2({
        // same options
});
```

it looks like that selectbox is destroyed but not initialized again. Because after another refresh, my console says:

```
The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.
```

Thanks for any answer, I'm new to this.

Comment: do both your selectboxes contain the same id? `#mySelect2`. Show some html

Comment: no, they are different

`<select name="subjects[]" class="form-control input-sm select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="frm-searchLecturesForm-form-subjects" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"> ... options ... </select>`

`<select name="topics[]" class="form-control input-sm select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="frm-searchLecturesForm-form-topics" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"> ... options ... </select>`

Comment: I apply select2 on both of them and both works... just until I change selected option in first select and refresh data in second select "#frm-searchLecturesForm-form-topics"

Comment: show me some real code and not an example

Answer (score 0):

Try not destroying the select2 element, loading new `data` [link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array) and then `.trigger('change')` [link](https://select2.github.io/options.html#what-events-does-select2-listen-for). For example:

```js
// new data arrived...
var new_data = [...]

$('#mySelect2').select2({
    // update data
    data: new_data
});
$('#mySelect2').trigger("change");
```

Comment: Its not working with my code.. my new_data is coming from Ajax Success.. but its appeding to current select box , So I am having issue with Old SelectBox data and its appending new data as well.. any solution for that so It will display only ajax return data?

Comment: $.post('/get_ajax_data/',{custom_param:1},
 function(data){
 var result = data.result;
 $("#client1_select").select2({
    data:result
 });
 $('#client1_select').trigger("change");
 });